# graphql-js Queries can be in any order, but apparently input types cannot

Tags: graphql-js

Attempting to follow an [example](https://medium.com/@HurricaneJames/graphql-mutations-fb3ad5ae73c4#.uqoxc79lb) of nested mutations:

It looks like with `graphql-js` I can have forward references for queries but not for mutations.

For example, if I have two types, `Person` and `User`, it is legal for Queries to have forward references:

```
const UserType = new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'UserType',
  description: 'A user',
  fields: () => ({
    uuid: {type: (graphql.GraphQLString)},
    person: {
      type: PersonType,
      resolve: (root, {args}, request ) => {
        return db.personGetByUUID(request.user, root.person);
      }
    },
  })
});
const PersonType = new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({ [...]
```

However this forward reference is not legal for mutations:

```
const UserInputType = new graphql.GraphQLInputObjectType({
  name: 'UserInputFields',
  description: 'input type for creation or update of a user',
  fields: {
    uuid: {type: (graphql.GraphQLString)},
    person: {type: (PersonInputType)},
  }
});

const PersonInputType = new graphql.GraphQLInputObjectType({ [...]
```

If I attempt this I get the error `ReferenceError: PersonInputType is not defined`

My understanding was that GraphQL allows you to start at any node in a graph an create a logical tree view for querying or mutating the graph.  This appears to be true for queries but not for mutations.

Is this a missing feature, limitation of Javascript, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can.

The `fields` property on GraphQL types, could be either an object, or a function that returns an object. When you need to reference a type that hasn't been defined yet, you simply wrap the whole `field` object inside a function. Just like what you did when defined `UserType`.

```
const UserInputType = new graphql.GraphQLInputObjectType({
  name: 'UserInputFields',
  description: 'input type for creation or update of a user',
  fields: () => ({ // <----------- function that returns the object
    uuid: {type: (graphql.GraphQLString)},
    person: {type: (PersonInputType)},
  })
});

const PersonInputType = new graphql.GraphQLInputObjectType({ [...]
```

Quoting from the [docs](http://graphql.org/graphql-js/type/#graphqlobjecttype):

> When two types need to refer to each other, or a type needs to refer to itself in a field, you can use a function expression (aka a closure or a thunk) to supply the fields lazily.

Comment: I shall give this a try.  Is this documented somewhere?   Finding anything more than very basic use cases has been difficult.

Comment: @PaulS I added a link to the docs. I believe you are right about the documentation, maybe the docs are not very clear about this.

Comment: It'd be nice if there was an example of a reasonably complex ERD implemented in graphql-js.  (for example showing two way references).  I'm now creating a TAO-like API for Redis w/ GraphQL as the front end, keep running into oddities.  Will possibly post those as separate questions..

Comment: @PaulS did my post answer your question? Anything else I can help with here?

Comment: yep, all good!.  I asked a question on nested mutations.  I'm pretty sure the answer is "probably shouldn't do that"...